# Bash grep in github action always exits with status 1

Tags: bash, grep, continuous-integration, github-actions

In a github workflow I am trying to check if the version of my project is SemVer compliant by using grep to check if the version match the [regexp for SemVer](https://regex101.com/r/Ly7O1x/3/).
I tried different ways to do it and never managed to reproduce the behaving of the script I developped on my local shell.
For example the following bash script successfully detect whether the TAG_NAME variable hold a SemVer version number:

```
    TAG_EXISTS="v3.0.12"
    SEMVER="^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-        Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$"

    grep -oE "$SEMVER" <<< "$TAG_EXISTS"
    ISSEMVER="$?"
    echo "$ISSEMVER"
```

returns 1
...and for TAG_EXISTS="3.0.12"
returns 0

But if I transfer this the following github workflow it alway returns 1 and I cannot find a way to got the result of grep or to asses the exit code of this operation:

```
    checkVersion:
    needs: tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.x

      .....some other not related steps

      - name: Check for Existing Tag
        id: check_tag
        run: |
          set +x
          TAG_EXISTS=3.0.14
          SEMVER="^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-        zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$"
          grep -oE "$SEMVER" <<< "$TAG_EXISTS"
          ISSEMVER="$?"
          echo "$ISSEMVER"
```

How can I make a github action fail if the grep does not find a match and make it pass if grep find a match?

I tried as well to grep in a subshell:

`RESULT=$( echo "$TAG_EXISTS" | grep -oE "$SEMVER")`

Like this the pipeline always fail and exits with status 1

Comment: Non-capturing groups aren't supported in `grep -E`. There's no need to distinguish between capturing and non-capturing groups, so use normal capturing groups.

Comment: How comes it works perfectly in bash? I need to use the regexp expression as it is, thus find a workaround to make this work in the gtihub workflow

Comment: I guess I was wrong. Maybe there's an issue with escaping in github action file, and you need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Your regex uses several features that aren't included in POSIX extended regex syntax, but that some implementations may support (note that on regex101.com, you're testing it using PCRE syntax, which is not what `grep -E` uses). Specifically, I see `\d` (use `[[:digit:]]` instead) and non-capturing groups. Also, there shouldn't be any spaces in `[0-9a-        zA-Z-]` -- replace that with `[0-9a-zA-Z-]`. See ["Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y).

Comment: Regarding [How comes it works perfectly in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145327/bash-grep-in-github-action-always-exits-with-status-1#comment135999398_77145327) - it is 100% impossible for that regexp to work in bash or any other shell. It may match some specific input strings but it doesn't "work" as it'll fail to match other strings that you want to match and may match some strings you do not want to match.

Comment: I notice you're using a here-string in your file, `grep -oE "$SEMVER" <<< "$TAG_EXISTS"`. A here-string is only supported in some shells, e.g. `bash`, it's not part of POSIX. Which shell is whatever is executing that file in your question using to execute it's `run:` section? If the answer isn't `bash` or some other shell that supports here-strings then you might want to use `printf '%s\n' "$TAG_EXISTS" | grep -oE "$SEMVER"` instead as that would work in any shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex in the post has a copy-paste error, I assume that in your actual script the part `[0-9a-        zA-Z-]` is actually `[0-9a-zA-Z-]`.

With the regex engine used by BSD `grep -E`, the pattern matches.

With the regex engine used by GNU `grep -E`, the pattern won't match, because it has constructs that don't work in BRE and ERE engines, only in PCRE (= Perl regexes) (thanks [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for the clarification). GNU `grep` supports PCRE with `-P`, and with that the pattern matches:

```
grep -qP "$SEMVER" <<< "$TAG_EXISTS"
```

(I changed `-o` to `-q` because it seems that's all you need here.)

However, since `-P` is only available in GNU implementations, at this point it's better to just use Perl, to have a portable solution:

```
perl -wln -e "/$SEMVER/ or exit(1)" <<< "$TAG_EXISTS"
```

Comment: Somehow it looks to work fine like using the P option. Thank for your answer

Comment: It's not directly about the implementation of `grep`, it's about the type of regexp the OP is using. They have `\d` in their regexp which means a literal `d` in a BRE (which grep uses by default) and in an ERE (which grep uses with `-E`) but means the same as the character class `[[:digit:]]` in a PCRE. They have other PCRE constructs in their regexp too. It's only somewhat related to the implementation of `grep` in as much as `-P` is a GNU grep extension that doesn't exist in other `grep`s, nor does it exist in any version of `awk` or `sed`. If you're going to use PCREs just use `perl`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for the insightful comment. I rewrote my post. Btw, apparently the pattern matches in OSX with `grep -E` ;-)

Comment: @janos it'll match some stings it should but not others it should and also some it shouldn't. The `\d` is actually undefined behavior but usually gets treated like `d` so my guess is the `\d*` allows for zero `d`s so `[1-9]\d*` would match `3` but not `30` as it should, but then it'll match strings that do contain `d`s like `3dd` and those shouldn't match. Also those `(?:` constructs are undefined behavior in an ERE so they're probably being ignored instead of being treated as a lookaround as intended meaning yet other strings that shouldn't match will match.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for your answers, very useful.